# Ubuntu 14 env cannot recognise python

Tags: 14.04, python

I have Ubuntu 14. When I run python I get

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
bash: /usr/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Python isn't installed for you by the looks. Or it was and has been removed but remnants left behind.

First, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python -y
```

Then try again. If that doesn't work, please post the output of `which python` and `ls -al /usr/bin/python*`.